# Woocommerce category text

Tags: php

I am trying to upgrade my SEO on my webshop. Anyone knows php could fix this puzzle. How can i fit this in each other?

How does this: `is_product_category( 'shirts' )` fit in this:

```
function woa_content_before_shop() {
    echo "<p>Insert your Content here...</p>";
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'woa_content_before_shop');
```

Answer (score 1):

WordPress [conditional tags](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/conditional-tags/) like `is_product_category()` can be used to change the displayed content based on the matched condition.

In this case you can use them to change the printed text based on `category`. You can exploit them in this way:

```
function woa_content_before_shop()
{
  if ( is_product_category( 'shirts' ) )
  {
    echo "<p>Here are shirts!</p>";
  } 
  else if ( is_product_category( 'games' ) )
  {
    echo "<p>Here are games!</p>";
  } 
  else
  {
    ...
  }
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'woa_content_before_shop');
```

Comment: Where do i copy it?

Comment: when i paste it in functions.php the site crashes

Comment: @Khatchik this is just a snippet to show you how it could be done! You can modify it and paste it at the end of the functions.php (if you have a template then use the functions.php of the template) - if something goes wrong your first move should be checking the log files.

Comment: require dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/framework/framework.php';

unset( $us_theme_supports );  under this?

Comment: @Khatchik I don't know what is in your `functions.php` - first verify if there is an active template, find the `functions.php` that is inside the folder of that template and simply put your new code at the end of it ! PS: I think you need to step back for a while and see how templates work in WordPress. You can have a look at this [tutorial](https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development) for example.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code. Also set your descriptions in Products > Categories.

```
function woa_content_before_shop() {
    if ( is_product_category() ) {
        global $wp_query;
        $id = $wp_query->get_queried_object_id();
        $desc = term_description( $id, 'product_cat' );
        if ( !empty( $desc ) ) {
            $output = '<p>' . esc_html( $desc ) . '</p>';
            echo $output;
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'woa_content_before_shop');
```